# What is the best way to represent the relationship between Team and Player in an ERD?

Tags: database-design, erd

I am working on designing an entity-relationship diagram (ERD) for a football system, I stopped in the relationship between the Player and Team entity types, as we know a player plays for only one team and a team have many players, so the relationship will be:

- `Team 1…* Player`

But, how can I represent this relation when a player can play in more than one team? In real life, a player has a contract with a team, when that contract ends, the player may continue with the same team or with other team, so the relation will be

- `Team *…* Player`, or
- `Team 1…* Contract *…1 Player`

**Questions**

- Is my understanding is well?
- Do you have any suggestions about the two scenarios?

Comment: Yes, the second approach is reasonable, if you want to store that info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a history of the all the players that have passed in that team the approach: `Team 1:N Contracts N:1 Players` is fine.
Otherwise if you just want to know the players that are currently in the team and contract is not a needed information for you, the approach: `Team 1:N Player` will also work